# How can I use vbetool as a non-root (mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted      Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).)

Tags: permissions, sudo

I would like to be able to turn off my screen upon a keypress. I need vbetool to do that (`xset dpms force off` just blanks it, does not turn it off). However, vbetool needs root priviledges. So I put line `my_user_name ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/vbetool"` into my sudoers file with visudo. However, when I run `vbetool dpms off`, it says

```
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns of the line to put to visudo needs to be as follows:

```
my_user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/vbetool
```

Then `sudo vbetool dpms off` works.

However, it seems `xset dpms force off` does the same thing after all. I think it did not work that way a couple of releases back, but now it works.

Comment: BTW: when assigning a two key shortcut (for example ctrl + e)to `xset dpms force off`, one needs to add delay to is since releasing the second key will turn the screen back on. So create a script 
    
    #!/bin/bash
    sleep 1
    xset dpms force off

and assign this script to a shortcut.